# mkusb persistent live boot configuration

Tags: boot, grub, usb-drive

I use [MKUSB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and it works brilliantly for eOS Loki persistent live.  However, I cannot work out how to edit the boot menu...  I can't find grub.cfg (which I've done before, but not on a MKUSB persistent live).  Anyone have experience with this?  Ideally I want to bypass the boot menu altogether, so it just boots straight to eOS on any system.

Comment: Update: I looked at gparted and i appears there is a 1MB partition which may contain the GRUB config files.  However I cannot mount sdb2 - it cannot identify the filesystem and says it may be "bad" - here's the output `mount: /dev/sdb2 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.`

Comment: Here's the gparted screenshot - see sdb2... http://imgur.com/a/KrAbL

Answer (score 1):

the configuration file is at:
`/FAT32_PARTITION/boot/grub.cfg`

**How I found out where the files are:**
By looking for the strings I see in the GRUB menu in the raw data on the USB drive, I found that the configuration files are located in a partition called "usbboot", which is FAT32 (the second partition in your screenshot, which is has a different name in your case, since I had this problem with Ubuntu).